# Visual Studio Enterprise GenericTest Test Run deployment issue

Tags: visual-studio, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I've built a GenericTest to associate a CasperJs test with a TFS test case.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<GenericTest name="Login With Email" storage="c:\development\testproject\tests\generic\login with email.generictest" id="0d5c40d3-2224-4adf-9a5b-7ef5b6e61f3a" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <DeploymentItems>
    <DeploymentItem filename="testproject\Site\Login\Index.js" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="testproject\Site\Settings.js" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="testproject\Site\Navigation.js" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="testproject\Site\History\Index.js" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="testproject\Tests\LoginWithEmail.js" />
  </DeploymentItems>
  <Command filename="C:\tools\CasperJs\1.1.b\bin\casperjs.exe" arguments="test &quot;testproject\Tests\LoginWithEmail.js&quot; --ignore-ssl-errors=true" maxDuration="0" workingDirectory="%TestOutputDirectory%" />
  <SummaryXmlFile path="%TestOutputDirectory%\&lt;Enter summary file name here&gt;" />
</GenericTest>
```

But when I run the test from test explorer I get the errors:

```html
Warning: Test Run deployment issue: Failed to get the file for deployment item 'testproject\Site\Login\Index.js' specified by the test 'login with email': System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\testproject\Site\Login\Index.js'.
Warning: Test Run deployment issue: Failed to get the file for deployment item 'testproject\Site\Settings.js' specified by the test 'login with email': System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\testproject\Site\Settings.js'.
Warning: Test Run deployment issue: Failed to get the file for deployment item 'testproject\Site\Navigation.js' specified by the test 'login with email': System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\testproject\Site\Navigation.js'.
Warning: Test Run deployment issue: Failed to get the file for deployment item 'testproject\Site\History\Index.js' specified by the test 'login with email': System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\testproject\Site\History\Index.js'.
Warning: Test Run deployment issue: Failed to get the file for deployment item 'testproject\Tests\LoginWithEmail.js' specified by the test 'login with email': System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\testproject\Tests\LoginWithEmail.js'.
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:14.346) ==========
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using relative paths in the DeploymentItems `filename` attribute.
The test runner seems to use `C:\Windows\system32` as Working directory when looking for those files (as per the error message).

Judging from the `storage` attribute in the GenericTest node, these files are located in `c:\development\testproject\`. So you'll have to add that to the path for your deployment items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<GenericTest name="Login With Email" storage="c:\development\testproject\tests\generic\login with email.generictest" id="0d5c40d3-2224-4adf-9a5b-7ef5b6e61f3a" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <DeploymentItems>
    <DeploymentItem filename="c:\development\testproject\Site\Login\Index.js" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="c:\development\testproject\Site\Settings.js" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="c:\development\testproject\Site\Navigation.js" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="c:\development\testproject\Site\History\Index.js" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="c:\development\testproject\Tests\LoginWithEmail.js" />
  </DeploymentItems>
  <Command filename="C:\tools\CasperJs\1.1.b\bin\casperjs.exe" arguments="test &quot;testproject\Tests\LoginWithEmail.js&quot; --ignore-ssl-errors=true" maxDuration="0" workingDirectory="%TestOutputDirectory%" />
  <SummaryXmlFile path="%TestOutputDirectory%\&lt;Enter summary file name here&gt;" />
</GenericTest>
```